# vsftpd adds server own domain name suffix to host name

Tags: domain, bind, vsftpd

I have the following issue with vsftp (and asterisk, by the way):

When I'm connecting from 37.229.152.222 to vsftpd server, I get timeout and lots of errors in bind log that is running on the same server:

```
error (unexpected RCODE 51) resolving '37-229-152-222-broadband.kyivstar.net.dcodeit.net/AAAA/IN': 78.47.84.170#53
error (unexpected RCODE 51) resolving '37-229-152-222-broadband.kyivstar.net.dcodeit.net/AAAA/IN': 82.196.1.175#53
error (unexpected RCODE 51) resolving '37-229-152-222-broadband.kyivstar.net.dcodeit.net/AAAA/IN': 89.184.83.201#53
error (unexpected RCODE 51) resolving '37-229-152-222-broadband.kyivstar.net.dcodeit.net/AAAA/IN': 2a01:4f8:d15:2287::2#53
```

(a lot of lines skipped)

I tried to resolve this issue. Timeouts are caused because my dns provider for dcodeit.net domain has lot of servers and they return timeouts for queries like

```
dig 37-229-152-222-broadband.kyivstar.net.dcodeit.net aaaa @ns10.uadns.com
```

But I want to find the problem root:

```
dig 222.152.229.37.in-addr.arpa ptr
```

properly returns "37-229-152-222-broadband.kyivstar.net.":

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
222.152.229.37.in-addr.arpa. 86400 IN   PTR     37-229-152-222-broadband.kyivstar.net.
```

Why vsftpd (or bind?) tries to add "dcodeit.net" as suffix (server name is "example.dcodeit.net") to FQDN?

/etc/resolv.conf:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

Software:

- CentOS release 6.7 (Final);
- bind 9.8.2-0.37.rc1 (from CentOS repo);
- vsftpd 3.0.2-2

Comment: As temporary workaround you can add 'reverse_lookup_enable=NO' to vsftpd.conf

Comment: I've already made a workaround in my hosts file: `37.229.152.222 37-229-152-222-broadband.kyivstar.net 37-229-152-222-broadband.kyivstar.net.dcodeit.net`, thanks. Just wanted to found the root of the problem: who does this suffix addition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be only reproduced with "vsftpd extended builds" taken from http://vsftpd.devnet.ru or from CentALT repository. I was not able to reproduce it any more with regular builds.